# Sending reports from my python script using gmail smtp

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to send email to myself with all reports collect each day from my scripts and below is the code I'm using to send the email.

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def send_email(message="", subject="EReport of Twitter Bot"):
    msg = MIMEText(message)

    # me == the sender's email address
    # you == the recipient's email address
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = 'r****@gmail.com'
    msg['To'] = 'r****@gmail.com'

    # Send the message via our own SMTP server, but don't include the
    # envelope header.
    try:
        s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',465)
        s.ehlo()
        s.starttls()
        s.ehlo()
        s.login('r****@gmail.com', 'mypassword')
        s.sendmail('r****@gmail.com', 'r****@gmail.com', msg.as_string())
        s.quit()
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if send_email(message="Hello Ravi!"):
        print "Successfully sent the mail"
    else:
        print "Sorry"
```

However, I get `Connection unexpectedly closed` when using the port 465. And If I use port 587 I get the following

```
(534, '5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvkf\n5.7.14 g4kEFJrti_fMva0wSRWGl4KfuNsFhQumLhgzMCUlPCQn2dvYdPCDr03l9luBP2XTwcnf_N\n5.7.14 BNsPV2jZhLOPjFOSYtGM16Wb6A1BlmLvMP1_mMHoeo4plSVNGio8EDCx_RMW7HcJdYcpx9\n5.7.14 T5SHwceKzRdpUXHxdL2icc0KAMDtb1dDLDr389N_s-tnSkylcN0bwctBA0tKF2k0AC6OsX\n5.7.14 jIcP7iV3ArV6PEB2ZXPCOI2gRPg0> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 lq10sm97657764pab.36 - smtp')
```

Which basically means my server is not trust worthy, although reverse-dns on my server's ip returns valid rent-history.com

Does anyone know what I can do/try to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Port 465 is used for SSL, port 587 not.

You should use SMTP_SSL when you intend to use secure connection (port 465), and SMTP with port 587.

Also, I'd like to point out [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail); I developed it.

You can just use:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP('r****@gmail.com', 'pw') # or yagmail.SMTP_SSL for port 465
yag.send('r****@gmail.com', "EReport of Twitter Bot", message)
```

Furthermore, it makes it easy to:

- write the script in a passwordless manner
- adding files by filenames (and it will automatically attach it using the correct mimetype)
- it automatically sends HTML emails and uses plain text fallback

Install using pip (works for both python 2 and 3):

```
pip install yagmail
```

Comment: Thanks for the information and its a cool plugin. But it did not help my case.

Comment: Try yagmail.SMTP_SSL perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to log into whatever gmail account you are using and go to the [less secure apps secion](http://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) to enable access via a less secure app, such as your program.  Obviously, this decreases the account's security, so I don't recommend you do this with a personal account.

Comment: I disabled the secure apps section, still it says the error(s) remain the same.

Comment: Actually, I just came across 'https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/postfix-smtp-debian7' which suits my requirement very close. Will check if that helps me.